# How folder locking works

Tags: windows, registry, logic, explorer, autoit

As windows doesn't provide password protection for individual folder, there are many third party software like 'Folder Lock' that does the job. I wanted to know the logic behind these kind of applications and found one code like this: ['lock-a-folder'](http://code.google.com/p/lock-a-folder/source/browse/lock-a-folder.au3). This is an AutoIt script which I am not familiar with. However, I just want to know the logic used here.

These are the main functions of the script I am interested in:

```
Func Lock($slected)
  Local $Temp,$TempFile
  If @error or $slected = "" Then Return("Empty selection/Cancel Pressed")
  If Not FileExists($slected) Then
    MsgBox(0, $AppName, $slected & " " & Lang('doesntexist'), 0, $WIN1)
    Return('doesntexist')
  EndIf
  Local $l0ckd = RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders")
  _DebugOut('RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders") = ' & $l0ckd)

  If Not StringInStr($l0ckd, $slected & ".{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}|") = 0 Then
    MsgBox(0, $AppName, $slected & " " & Lang('alreadyinlist'), 0, $WIN1)
    Return('alreadyinlist')
  EndIf
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then
    GUICtrlSetData($List1, "")
    GUICtrlSetData($List1, Lang('plzwait') & "....")
    GUISetState(@SW_DISABLE)
  EndIf
  _DebugOut($slected)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then GUISetState(@SW_ENABLE)
  If DirMove($slected, $slected & ".{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}") = 0 Then
  FileSetAttrib($slected, "-RSH")
  MsgBox(0, $AppName, $slected & " " & Lang('unable2lock'), 0, $WIN1)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then Readfolders()
    Return('unable2lock')
  EndIf
  $slected = $slected & ".{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}"
  FileSetAttrib($slected, "+RSH")
  $l0ckd &= $slected & "|"
  _DebugOut("$l0ckd &= $slected| = " & $l0ckd)
  $debug = RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders", "REG_SZ", $l0ckd)
  _DebugOut('RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders", "REG_SZ", $l0ckd) = ' & $debug)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then Readfolders()
  Return("Done")
EndFunc ;==>Lock


Func UnLock($slected)
  _DebugOut($slected)
  If $slected = "" Or @error Then
    MsgBox(0, $AppName, Lang('selectfirst'), 0, $WIN1)
    Return("Empty selection/Cancel Pressed")
  EndIf
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then
    GUICtrlSetData($List1, "")
    GUICtrlSetData($List1, Lang('plzwait') & "....")
    GUISetState(@SW_DISABLE)
  EndIf
  Local $Temp = StringReplace($slected, ".{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}", "", 0, 2)
  _DebugOut("$Temp = " & $Temp)
  FileSetAttrib($slected, "-RSH")
  Local $Temp1
  $Temp1 = DirMove($slected, $Temp)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then GUISetState(@SW_ENABLE)
  If $Temp1 = 0 Then
    $Temp1 = DirMove($slected, $Temp & ".recovered")
  EndIf
  If $Temp1 = 0 Then

  MsgBox(0, $AppName, $slected & " " & Lang('unable2unlock'), 0, $WIN1)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then Readfolders()
    Return('unable2unlock')
  EndIf
  Local $l0ckd = RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders")
  _DebugOut('RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders") = ' & $l0ckd)
  $Temp = StringReplace($l0ckd, $slected & "|", "")
  _DebugOut('StringReplace($l0ckd, $slected & "|", "")' & " = " & $Temp)
  $debug = RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders", "REG_SZ", $Temp)
  _DebugOut('RegWrite("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\" & $AppName, "lockedfolders", "REG_SZ", $l0ckd) = ' & $debug)
  If $CmdLine[0] = 0 Then Readfolders()
  Return("Done")
EndFunc ;==>UnLock
```

Can anybody please tell me the logic?

Comment: I could be wrong but it looks like the script simply copies the folder to some "hidden" location, and move it back when you type a password.

Comment: You are right @Laurent. Renaming the folder to something like this also works:_“Control Panel.{21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D}”_. But here it seems the absolute folder path is appended to some registry value. So it works for multiple folders. If it is copying the folder to a hidden location, then how to create a location like that? I want a script/program that will lock/hide completely any number of folder I want. Please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script creates registry entries like :

```
HKCR\CLSID\{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}
HKCR\CLSID\{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}\shell\open
HKCR\CLSID\{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}\shell\explore
HKCR\CLSID\{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}\shell\opennewwindow
HKCR\CLSID\{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}\shell\opennewprocess
```

and

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\$AppName\lockedfolders
```

When locking a folder, it is renamed like `FolderName.{90F8C996-7C70-4331-9D70-FB357D559FD5}` and this name gets appended to the value of `HKCU\SOFTWARE\$AppName\lockedfolders` for future reference.

When unlocking it just changes the folder back to its original name, removing the entry from the registry value.

So it seems not secure at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this in command line:

```
C:> attrib +a +H +S folder_name
```

to remove attributes replace `+` with `-`